# Probability of time between two events in a poisson process

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Suppose  people arrive at a certain place according  to  a  poisson process with rate 10 per day.
1) What is the expected  time until the arrival of 100 person.
2) What  is  the  probability  that  time  between  100th and 200 th arrival exceeds 10 days ?

I think the answer to 1)is 10 as sum of iid exponentials follow a gamma distribution with parameter 10. Thus expected  time =$100 \over 10$=10.
 But I don' tunderstand part 2.
 Can someone  please  show  me  how to do it.

Comment: The time $T$ between the 100th and 200th arrival is the sum of 100 i.i.d. exponential random variables with mean $\frac1{10}$. Once this is recognized, either you use the known PDF of $T$ to estimate $P(T>10)$, or you note that $10=E(T)$ and that 100 is "large" hence by the CLT, $P(T>E(T))\approx\frac12$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Poisson process is a process with independent increments, question 2) is equivalent to question: What is the probability that time between 1st and 100th arrival exceeds 10 days? (As Did correctly said in his comment.)

Solving this equivalent question is quite simple: Since the number of arrivals in interval (0; 10] follows a Poisson distribution, probabilities of $k$ arrivals in (0; 10] are given by formula $\frac{e^{-\lambda \cdot 10} \cdot (\lambda \cdot 10)^k}{k!}$.

Because $\lambda =10$ (intensity of your process) and you have to count the probability that $k < 100$, the exact solution is $\sum^{99}_{k=0} \frac{e^{-100}\cdot 100^{k}}{k!}$ which is approximately $0.4867$.